# Assign new column based on unique combinations of values in other columns

Tags: r, indexing, combinations, factors

I have a dataset of bird observation records, about 300,000 rows, with 7 columns. I want to create a new column based on the unique combinations of 3 other columns, all of which are factor variables - "gridref", the 1km grid square in which the record is located; "observer", the person who made the observation and "date", date of the observation. I want to create a new column, "visit_ID", for each unique "visit" to a 1km grid square - that is, each unique combination of gridref, observer and date.

I tried using the following code:

`birds_raw$vid <- as.integer(interaction(birds_raw$gridref, birds_raw$observer, birds_raw$date))`

This returns the following error message:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 636.1 Gb
In addition: Warning message:
In ans * length(l) : NAs produced by integer overflow
```

I'm sure there must be a simple way to achieve this. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Perhaps use `paste` instead of `interaction` i.e. `v1 <- paste(birds_raw$gridref, birds_raw$observer, birds_raw$date); birds_raw$vid <- match(v1, unique(v1))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this efficiently with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
birds_raw <-
  data.table(
    other_var = factor(c("other 1", "other 2", "other 3", "other 4")),
    gridref = factor(c("grid 1", "grid 2", "grid 1", "grid 1")),
    observer = factor(c("person 1", "person 2", "person 2", "person 1")),
    date = factor(c("date 1", "date 2", "date 1", "date 1"))
  )
birds_raw[, visit_id := .GRP, by = c("gridref", "observer", "date")][]
```

Comment: Thanks @Giovanni Colitti, I'm not familiar with the data.table package though. When I try to run the code

'birds_raw[, visit_id := .GRP, by = c("gridref", "observer", "date")][]'

I get the following error message: 'Error in `[.data.frame`(birds_raw, , `:=`(visit_id, .GRP), by = c("gridref",  : 
  unused argument (by = c("gridref", "observer", "date"))'

any ideas what happened there?

Comment: Not sure why only some random bits of that comment are being formatted as code...

Comment: `birds_raw` has to be a `data.table` not a `data.frame`. Since you don't give us an example data set to work with, I created an example. You can try using `as.data.table(birds_raw)` to coerce a `data.frame` to a `data.table`.